# RabbitMQ: Fast processing of time consuming events

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm experimenting with RabbitMQ and I hope someone can give me some hints.

I try to do the following: Processing events, which are time consuming to process, as quickly as possible with one consumer.

The test: 5 events and each one takes 2 seconds to process.

First attempt: 'Hello world' example from RabbitMQ (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Sender

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost"};
    using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

    const string message = "Hello World!";

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{message} {i}");
        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,
                                routingKey: "hello",
                                basicProperties: null,
                                body: body);

        Console.WriteLine($"Sent {message} {i}");
    }

    // Consumer

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Received {message}");
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                            autoAck: true,
                            consumer: consumer);


    Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Conclusion:  Too slow because events are processed synchronously.

Second attempt: Asynchronous processing using AsyncEventingBasicConsumer.

Code changes:

- DispatchConsumersAsync-property is set in the ConnectionFactory
- AsyncEventingBasicConsumer is used
- consumer.Received is async

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Sender

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
    using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

    const string message = "Hello World!";

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{message} {i}");
        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,
                                routingKey: "hello",
                                basicProperties: null,
                                body: body);

        Console.WriteLine($"Sent {message} {i}");
    }

    // Consumer

    var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Received {message}");
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                            autoAck: true,
                            consumer: consumer);


    Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Conclusion:  Too slow because events are still processed synchronously.

Third attempt: Async event handler for the consumer.
Code changes:

- DispatchConsumersAsync-property is removed in the ConnectionFactory.
- EventingBasicConsumer is used again

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Sender

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
    using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

    const string message = "Hello World!";

    for (int i = 1; i <= 101; i++)
    {
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{message} {i}");
        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,
                                routingKey: "hello",
                                basicProperties: null,
                                body: body);

        Console.WriteLine($"Sent {message} {i}");
    }

    // Consumer

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Received {message}");
    };

    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                            autoAck: true,
                            consumer: consumer);


    Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Conclusion:  This is the result I want.  The messages are processed very fast even when 1000 events are published.

But is this a proper solution for usage in a production environment?
I hope someone can help to clarify this or share their experience for processing events fast in a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd approach is definitely the correct way. I've been using it in production for a long time and it's crazy fast.

Also, the messages should be processed in parallel if you use that approach. Just make sure you set an approriate prefetch value.

Also, you might want to consider giving publisher confirms a try.